# When uploading an Outlook .msg file in Rails, can I tell if it has attachments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload

In Rails 2.3, I upload Outlook .msg files but I want to kick them out if they contain attachments. Does anyone know of a way to detect if the file has attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ruby msg](https://github.com/aquasync/ruby-msg) gem.
It's documented well enough to help you to solve your problem.
Your code may look like this

```
require 'mapi/msg'

msg = Mapi::Msg.open 'email.msg'
if msg.attachments.present?
  # ...reject msg processing...
else
  # ...process msg...
end
```

[Microsoft docs on msg format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912(v=exchg.80).aspx) can help you to understood msg-file structure.

Comment: Thanks so much, this looks like a great lead. If I wanted to strip out any attachments...do you know if the gem supports that? I don't see anything to indicate so in their docs.